# Not getting message from FireBase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to learn the basics to FireBase and implement it in my app. I found an example at the following website. I created a new class and tried to send a message, but it never showed up in my logcat.

**EDIT**: After trying many different things, I decided to upload my code to a git repo so someone can look at ALL the code and see if they can figure out why I am not getting the messages. The code can be found at:

https://bitbucket.org/alexander7567/msw-android/src

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: are you extending FirebaseMessagingService?

Comment: @Linxy Unfortunately I don't really know how to tell.. But I would gladly provide whatever you needed. I just copied the code straight from their website to test.

Comment: Does the class which contains the method: @Override public void onMessageReceived.... , extend FirebaseMessagingService like: `public class MyClassName extends FirebaseMessagingService {}`

Comment: So I got to looking into what you was talking about, and I quickly learned I had to create a new class with the extends Fire.... So I got rid of that error. However, I am still not getting the messages in the logcat. I will update my question with my new question..

Comment: I quickly revised your code on Bitbucket and It seems to be Ok.
Are you using the Firebase console to send the notifications or are you usign your own server implementation to send the notifications?
If you are using your own server implementation please post the code in which you prepare the request JSON or plain text to send the notification.

Comment: @georgeLBA thanks for taking the time to do that. I am using the console for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@alexander7567 I have tested with an application that I have and when I send the messages from the firebase console the `onMessageReceived` method is not being called. But when I send the notifications from my own server implementation the method is called. For that reason you are not getting anything in the logcat. But you should be receiving the notifications in the system tray on your device.

Comment: I did a little further testing, and in an avd running 6.0 it worked as expected. Then I tried it again on my 5.0 phone nothing. Tried it on a 5.1 avd and nothing. I will try out your theory and report back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - you were correct. When sending from the Firebase console, I get the notification in android 6.0 and 4.4, but not 5 and 5.1. However, when I send from my server, I get it on all devices.